# Pandas UDF returns Array Type column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I want to write a Pandas UDF function with GroupMAP like this:

```
schema_str = "ID string,  EVENTS array<string>"

@pandas_udf(schema_str, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)

def my_udf(key, data):
  
  # Creates DataFrame.
  zero_row = np.zeros(shape=(1,2))
  column_names = ["ID", "EVENTS"]
  seq_df = pd.DataFrame(zero_row, columns=column_names)
  
  seq_df['ID'] = "aaa"
  seq_df['EVENTS'] = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
    
    
  return seq_df


df_seq= my_df.groupby("ID").apply(my_udf)
```

I have simplified the udf function to non related to the input data. It is just creating a dataframe with two columns, one is ID, another is Array String Type. But I still got error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 190 in stage 20.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 190.3 in stage 20.0 (TID 4817, 10.139.64.14, executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 480, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 472, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 408, in dump_stream
    timely_flush_timeout_ms=self.timely_flush_timeout_ms)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 215, in dump_stream
    for batch in iterator:
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 398, in init_stream_yield_batches
    for series in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 136, in <lambda>
    return lambda k, v: [(wrapped(k, v), to_arrow_type(return_type))]
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 124, in wrapped
    result = f(key, pd.concat(value_series, axis=1))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<command-4469558475436012>", line 21, in count_transition
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3370, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3445, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3630, in _sanitize_column
    value = sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 519, in sanitize_index
    raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of index')
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Could anyone help me to check

Comment: `seq_df['EVENTS'] = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])` this line makes no sense. You have one row in your dataframe but you're assigning a column with 4 rows.

Comment: if you want an array column use [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]